# Bootstrap Carousels: 100% image width then centered, but with vertical portion cropped off so that there is no scroll

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5, tsx

If relevant, I am working with React. I prefer to use as many bootstrap classes as possible to keep things clean. I've tried a number of things. Currently I've got:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <img src="src/assets/lightning.jpg" className="w-100 overflow-y-hidden" />
  );
}
```

And it's definitely not working. The scroll bar for the page is still there.

I've then moved the `overflow-y-hidden` over to the root element in `index.html`. Also didn't fix the issue.

It's worth emphasizing that this is a simpler means towards the final goal of having a responsive carousel. So while some solutions may work for an image fitting the viewport as desired, it might not work for the carousel.

What did work was adding `vw-100 vh-100` to the images, but that's just the equivalent of having 100% viewport width and height. Which is fine as a temporary solution, but definitely not the result I'm going for as it stretches out the images accordingly rather than cropping them. (Again, root still has `overflow-y-hidden` as well.)

I then tried to have `vw-100 overflow-y-hidden` on the images, which works. But the carousel text on the bottom disappears, as well as buttons below it.

I am working with the example in the "Captions" section [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#captions).